# How to select one object in JSON array string using Java Regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this String (please note that I must use this as string, not converted to JSON).

```
String cats = "[{'_id':'abxyz','image':'http://127.0.0.1/abxyz.png','name':'Tabby Cat'},{'_id':'xyzr2','image':'http://127.0.0.1/abxr2.png','name':'Calico Cat'},{'_id':'ghjkl','image':'http://127.0.0.1/ghjkl.png','name':'Persian Cat'},{'_id':'ojr12','image':'http://127.0.0.1/ojr12.png','name':'Angora Cat'}]";
```

or for better readability: (there is no white space between object)

```
String cats =
"[{'_id':'abxyz','image':'http://127.0.0.1/abxyz.png','name':'Tabby Cat'},\
{'_id':'xyzr2','image':'http://127.0.0.1/abxr2.png','name':'Calico Cat'},\
{'_id':'ghjkl','image':'http://127.0.0.1/ghjkl.png','name':'Persian Cat'},\
{'_id':'ojr12','image':'http://127.0.0.1/ojr12.png','name':'Angora Cat'}]";
```

I want to extract the Calico Cat object using regex. I tried to use

```
String pattern = "{\'_id\':\'xyzr2\'.*}"
```

Unfortunately, the selection expands from Calico Cat to Angora Cat:

```
{'_id':'xyzr2','image':'http://127.0.0.1/abxr2.png','name':'Calico Cat'},\
{'_id':'ghjkl','image':'http://127.0.0.1/ghjkl.png','name':'Persian Cat'},\
{'_id':'ojr12','image':'http://127.0.0.1/ojr12.png','name':'Angora Cat'}
```

What kind of regex pattern I need to isolate only the Calico Cat?
Expected result:

```
{'_id':'xyzr2','image':'http://127.0.0.1/abxr2.png','name':'Calico Cat'}
```

Comment: "I want to extract the Calico Cat object using regex." Why don't you want to use a JSON parser? That's the natural approach to, y'know, parsing JSON...

Comment: I'm curious, what's the reason that you don't want to parse this?

Comment: That's the limitation imposed by the challenge, that's why. Also to enhance my RegEx understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it non-greedy to get smallest possible match

```
String pattern = "{\'_id\':\'xyzr2\'.*?}"
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/pO4fW2/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

or use following regex

```
String pattern = "{\'_id\':\'xyzr2\'[^}]*}"
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/pO4fW2/2)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

**FYI** : Always it's better to use json parser instead of hard coded regex, since the data is in valid json. Refer : [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)